# Cannot Create Extension vacuumlo postgresql 9.4

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I tried to CREATE EXTENSION vacuumlo, but it fails with the following message:

> "/usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/vacuumlo.control": no such file or directory.

I can see other `.sql` and `.control` files in that directory, and I was able to CREATE EXTENSION pgstattuple from it, but the vacuumlo files are indeed missing.

This is a VERY old server, and neither I nor others at the client have any PG experience (those that configured the server and apps are long gone).

I was told to use this tool to determine pg_largeobject bloat on this thread:

[pg_largeobject bloat](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/307499/production-postgresql-space-issue-huge-pg-largeobject-newbie-thrown-off-the-de)

How can I compile/use vacuumlo if the code is not in that directory?

Comment: Vacumlo is not an extension: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/vacuumlo.html it's a binary that should have been installed when the contrib module was installed

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly I cannot see how to MARK it as answered. I will check the forum docs to see if I can figure it out.